# How can I find the way back to the runway?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

Kerbal Space Program doesn't seem to have an option to plant flags in EVA anymore.  How can I find my way back to the runway I launched a Space Plane from without using a mod?

Answer (score 3):

You need to upgrade your Astronaut Complex to level 2 in order to gain the ability to plant flags on EVA. Beyond that, I'm afraid you'll have to either leave some debris at the KSC, or remember the geography around it.